# Save info if one switch is toggled

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show a displayalert if either of the switches are toggled.

This is my if statement:

```
 if(!SwitchOne.IsToggled || !SwitchTwo.IsToggled)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Cannot save", "Enter info.", "Ok");
        }
```

I want the info to be saved when 1 or both of the switches are toggled. However, it doesn't seem to care about the || in the if statement. When I toggled both switches I'm able to save the page and the DisplayAlert doesn't show = great. When I toggle only one switch the DisplayAlert shows. I don't understand why since I have || in the if statement.

I don't want the DisplayAlert to show if I toggle any switch.
Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: I think you want XOR, not OR.

Comment: You need to use && for the case you are describing.

Comment: No, I want either or. Not both. @CodePope

Comment: `true || false == true`, `true && false == false`. Which one do you want..? Remember your condition is testing if the switch is **not** toggled (which makes it a little more confusing). But in the end you want it to read, "if switch one is not toggled AND switch two is not toggled, then cannot save"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you need to use `&&`:

```
if(!SwitchOne.IsToggled && !SwitchTwo.IsToggled)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Cannot save", "Enter info.", "Ok");
        }
```

Now it will only show the alert if both  of the switches aren't toggled. If any of them are toggled, the alert is not shown right now.

```
 switch1 == toggled | switch2 == toglled
        true        |       true            =>      Do not show alert
        true        |       false           =>      Do not show alert
        false       |       true            =>      Do not show alert
        false       |       false           =>      show alert
```

Comment: I need the alert to be shown when only one switch is toggled too. @CodePope

Comment: @KalleP In the question you said "I want the info to be saved when 1 or both of the switches are toggled.". Now you are saying the opposite. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Im sorry, I misunderstood. It works nicely, thanks alot! @CodePope

Comment: @IvanIčin, if you read his question and the point I am asking, you will recognize there is contradiction. My reply was also confirmed by two others. Your comment is rude and impolite and violates the rules of stackoverflow. Please be respectful.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the switches are off so obviously if just one switch is off it will show the message and if both aren't it won't... You should:

```
if(SwitchOne.IsToggled || SwitchTwo.IsToggled)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Cannot save", "Enter info.", "Ok");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

`if (!SwitchOne.IsToggled && !SwitchTwo.IsToggled)`

If only one switch is toggled (say, `SwitchOne`), it'll evaluate to:

`if (!true && !false)` =>  `if (false & true)` =>  `if (false)`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to read if you reversed everthing, because right now you're testing the negative conditions for a negative response (if switch one is not toggled and switch two is not toggled then we can't save), which sometimes can be confusing to read.

This may be more readable:

```
if (SwitchOne.IsToggled || SwitchTwo.IsToggled)
{
    // At least one switch is toggled - we can save! 
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Cannot save", "Enter info.", "Ok");
}
```